# How to upgrade to Firefox Quantum in Ubuntu from existing firefox without adding ppa?

Tags: firefox

I don't want to add the official Mozilla ppa. Any other solution that does not require me to uninstall my current version (since I don't want to lose the placing and sequence of extensions and visual bookmark icons) is welcome. I am currently running version 56.

Comment: Please note that this is not a programming question :) A more appropriate place would have been [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com).

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Community Help Wiki has a [nice article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion/MozillaBuilds#Manual_Installation) about performing a manual installation. It boils down to:

- Download Firefox for Linux on the [official website](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/).
- Unpacking the archive in a directory.
- Making a backup of the current `~/.mozilla` directory.
- Running firefox with `firefox -no-remote -P mozilla-official`.

The last command will make sure to run the new Firefox on a new profile (`mozilla-official`) and that you can run both the old version and the new version at the same time (`-no-remote`).